# Google dataflow streaming pipeline doesn't process messages after the initial drain

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Goolge dataflow pipeline written using Apache beam [java], which consumes data from Google cloud subscription. The input data is windowed with a session window:

```
inputMessages.apply("WindowTransform", Window.into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(5)))
        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardDays(7))
        .triggering(
                AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)
        )
        .discardingFiredPanes());
```

The problem is, everything works fine for the initial drain but once all the messages are consumed from the subscription, pipeline won't consume any new messages. There are no error messages as well. I've to manually resubmit the job to process messages again, but it again stops processing new messages which were not part of the initial drain.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Hi @testuserx, I'll need a little more information. What kind of source are you using? And is it bounded or unbounded?

Comment: Can you describe more your process? Do you use PubSub as well ? Also, can you tell me if there is any activity in the job monitoring ?